# Is it possible that I got a virus without clicking what I downloaded?

Tags: windows-7, virus, anti-virus, malware, virus-removal

A couple of days ago I accidentally downloaded a file that looked very shady. My antivirus (Avira) pinged me that the file was suspicious, so I immediately deleted it, and then cleared my browsers downloads and also emptied the recycling bin. It was a .exe file, so it was very obviously a virus.

Then, just now a few minutes ago while I was browsing reddit, I noticed a tiny popup window in the top left of my screen which flashed by super quickly, and then disappeared, without me being able to notice what it said.

Is it possible that I infected myself, despite not clicking the .exe file?

I have run a full scan by Avira, and I just downloaded Malwarebytes and ran a scan of that too. Malwarebytes found one threat ("Stubinstaller.exe or something, which internet told me was nothing dangerous), while Avira found "OpenCandy.Gen" which was then moved to quarantine.

Did I infect my computer, or was the popup (likely) something unrelated?

(In case it is relevant, I am running a 64bit Windows 7)

EDIT: I just found the logs in Avira of the event; It shows it found "PUA/EDownloader.Gen7", and that "Access denied" action was performed.

EDIT2: I am using Chrome

EDIT3: This is not a duplicate of [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit) this. I am asking "Is it possible that I have been infected", not "how to remove a known infection".

Comment: There are drive-by viruses that execute in the JavaScript of some pages. You haven't mentioned the browser you were using?

Comment: I forgot to mention that; I am using Chrome. I'm not too good with JavaScript, but doing that sounds like I'd need to visit some risky website for it to do that, right? As in, the website itself intentionally tries to infect me, and it has nothing to do with files I downloaded earlier? I know Reddit is safe, so that can't be it

Comment: Try running the AV scan in safe-mode.

Comment: By "AV scan" you mean Avira, right?

Why would safe-mode help? I'm currently running it again (I went and updated it, and it said one file updated, so I'm running it again just in case), but I can do that as well once that's done